# Add comment to issue using php and JIRA SOAP API

Tags: php, jira

How do I add a comment to a JIRA Issue using PHP and Jura's SOAP API? I have the connection and tested it retrieving an existing issue, all runs good, but when I try the addComment method it returns this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server.userException] org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad types (class java.util.HashMap -> class com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.beans.RemoteComment) in /home/a7348186/public_html/jira.php:46 Stack trace: 
>   #0 /home/a7348186/public_html/jira.php(46): SoapClient->__call('addComment', Array)
>  
>   #1 /home/a7348186/public_html/jira.php(46):
>   SoapClient->addComment('16VGN3ohoo', 'NTP->29', Array) 
>   #2 {main}  thrown in /home/a7348186/public_html/jira.php on line 46

This is my code:

```
<?php
$emailplain = $_REQUEST['plain'];
$emailsubject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$inputkey = $_REQUEST['key'];
$inputsumm = $_REQUEST['summ'];
$client = new SoapClient(NULL,
    array(
        "location" => "https://server.com/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl",
        "uri"      => "urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes",
        "style"    => SOAP_RPC,
        "use"      => SOAP_ENCODED
        ));
$token = $client->login("user", "pass");
$issueId = $inputkey;
$issue = $client->getIssue($token, $issueId);
echo("assignee:".$issue->assignee);
echo(" created:".$issue->created);
echo(" summary:".$issue->summary);
echo(" issueid:".$issue->key);
print $inputsumm;
$stringsummary = $issue->summary;

$string = $issue->summary;
$emailsubjectregexp = preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z]+/', '', $inputsumm);
$stringsumm = ('summary ~ "' . $emailsubjectregexp . '"');
$jqlstring = $stringsumm;

$searchjql = $client->getIssuesFromJqlSearch($token, $jqlstring, 100);
function printArray ($array, $devolver = false) {
    $stringa = '<pre>' . print_r($array, true) . '</pre>';
    if ($devolver) return $stringa;
    else echo $stringa;
}
printArray($searchjql);
print_r ($searchjql);
$key = $searchjql[0]->key;
echo $key;
$client->addComment($token, $key, array('body' => 'your comment'));
?>
```

If you notice, the last line contains the code to execute what I want, but with no luck. Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you create the Soap client object, change :

```
$client = new SoapClient(NULL,
    array(
        "location" => "https://server.com/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl",
        "uri"      => "urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes",
        "style"    => SOAP_RPC,
        "use"      => SOAP_ENCODED
        ));
```

to:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://jira.watchitoo.com/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl");
```

This should work.

Full add comment code:

```
$issueKey = "key-123";
$username= "JiraUser";
$password= "JiraPassword";
$jiraAddress = "https://your.jira.com/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl";
$myComment = "your comment";

$soapClient = new SoapClient($jiraAddress);
$token = $soapClient->login($username, $password);
$soapClient->addComment($token, $issueKey, array('body' => $myComment));
```

Comment: i have tried your code but returns this: "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://server.com/jira/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl' : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /home/a7348186/public_html/jira.php:52 Stack trace: #0 /home/a7348186/public_html/jira.php(52): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://scratch...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/a7348186/public_html/jira.php on line 52"                       i tried that when i started this project and returned the same error that's why i opted for array SOAPClient

Comment: @user1608381 What is your Jira version? which os? which 'php-soap'? please update the detail in your question.

Comment: JIRA 5.0.6 - was installed via CentOS - PHP version: 5.2.17

Comment: which `php-soap`? run `rpm -qa| grep soap` to get the version